# Why is Spring ServiceLocatorFactoryBean not recommended for Singletons?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am implementing a service locator pattern in Spring using the ServiceLocatorFactoryBean as described here: https://springframework.guru/service-locator-pattern-in-spring/

I have multiple Parser implementations and want to select the correct one at runtime to handle the request. Each Parser implements the `parse(String)` method.

```java
    @Autowired
    private ParserFactory parserFactory;

    @PostMapping("/parse/{format}")
    public String parse(@PathVariable String format, @RequestBody String content) {
        return parserFactory.getParser(format).parse(content);
    }
```

```
    @Bean("parserFactory")
    public FactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean() {
        ServiceLocatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setServiceLocatorInterface(ParserFactory.class);
        return factoryBean;
    }
```

(Note that is a very simplistic example. Security, service, error handling, etc. omitted).

This works, but the [ServiceLocatorFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html) documentation says this:

> Such service locators permit the decoupling of calling code from the
>   BeanFactory API, by using an appropriate custom locator interface.
>   They will typically be used for prototype beans, i.e. for factory
>   methods that are supposed to return a new instance for each call. The
>   client receives a reference to the service locator via setter or
>   constructor injection, to be able to invoke the locator's factory
>   methods on demand. **For singleton beans, direct setter or constructor injection of the target bean is preferable.**

How does that bolded part relate to my use case? My services are all singletons and setter or construction injection is not an option as I won't know the requested parser type until the request comes into the controller.